# Authorization header is not set with PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl, header

I'm trying to make an API-call from PHP using cURL.

This is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/api/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array('sql' => $sql)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: MY-API-KEY'));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

It seems as if the Authorization-header is not set. I've tried to Google around, where some say that the header is not recognized correctly. Can anyone help?
My code does work for API-calls without Authorization needed.

UPDATE:
Calling the command via the command line tool curl:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: MY-API-KEY'...
```

everything works.

My feedback from the PHP cURL is "Access denied".

Comment: I run your code w/ PHP 5.4 - the Authorization-Header /is/ set (I checked w/ http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html). So I would guess that the problem is on the API side. Good luck!

Comment: What is the `$response` you get? Also check `curl_error()`.

Comment: I'm not getting an error message from cURL, but I'm getting "Access denied" from the API.

Answer (score 1):

Because it does't look its constructed properly:

Client side:

When the user agent wants to send the server authentication credentials it may use the Authorization header.

The Authorization header is constructed as follows:

Username and password are combined into a string "username:password"
The resulting string is then encoded using the RFC2045-MIME variant of Base64, except not limited to 76 char/line
The authorization method and a space i.e. "Basic " is then put before the encoded string.
For example, if the user agent uses 'Aladdin' as the username and 'open sesame' as the password then the header is formed as follows:

Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==

Comment: Calling the same command from the command line tool curl everything works. This is the API I'm trying to call: http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.1.1/api.html#authentication-and-api-keys